# AWS KMS manual key rotation and old encrypted data

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I'm trying to enable client-side encryption for the data uploaded to AWS S3 by following the guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/kms-keys-s3-encryption.html.
I have created a CMK in KMS with the automatic rotation disabled and alias `test`. It's all working fine, I can upload the encrypted data to s3 and then decrypt it from s3.
I'm trying to perform manual rotation by following the guide here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html (Rotating keys manually)
As per docs I need to create a new KMS key and update the alias to `test`.
Now I want to get and decrypt the data that is already uploaded to s3 but was encrypted with an old key. I'm getting this (I'm using alias not keyId in the app):

```
The key ID in the request does not identify a CMK that can perform this operation
```

It makes sense because it's a different key and it would be strange if I can use any key to decrypt the data. From what I read, with the automatic rotation you get this behaviour for free but what about manual rotation? Do I need to decrypt all the data and encrypt it with the new key? Maybe can I somehow create a new KMS key with the same key material so it would work similarly to automatic rotation?

The misleading part is a **Note** on the docs page saying:

```
Note
When you begin using the new KMS key, be sure to keep the original KMS key enabled so that AWS KMS can decrypt data that the original KMS key encrypted.
```

This would suggest that I can just change the alias and should be able to decrypt the data with the new CMS key? What am I missing?

```
var kmsEncryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterialsV2("alias/test", KmsType.KmsContext, new Dictionary<string, string>());

 var s3EncClient = new AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2(credentials, config, kmsEncryptionMaterials);

 var result = await s3EncClient.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest() {Key = "upload-test", BucketName = configuration.Bucket});
```

Comment: The docs should be clearer yes. However for decryption, you shouldn’t specify the alias or key ID - let AWS figure it out automatically. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary What does that mean? I updated the original post with the code. To build AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 it requires key Id or key alias. The exception is thrown when I call GetObjectAsync if object was encrypted with the previous CMS key. I think there is no way to not specify key.

Comment: Do `GetObjectAsync` with a normal S3 client, with credentials that have full access to your KMS keys - what do you get back then?  `aws kms decrypt` will get the key ID from the encrypted cipher text however S3 KMS encryption may be different in this regard & require a key... worth a try however.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary GetObjectAsync returns encrypted data object with normal S3 client. I trued to decrypt it manually with AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient.Decrypt but it throws an error.

Comment: Happy to be proven wrong but I assume S3 encryption has additional steps that doesn't allow you to just `kms decrypt` something. If so, the best way would be to keep a link between the key used and the file when you encrypt it in your application so you can then reference it later on.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thank you for your answers. I will discuss if manual rotation is required in our case, and if it is, I'll investigate further and update the answer if I find out :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thank you for help Ermiya. I missed the part about getting key id from encrypted cipher text, that was the bit which I didn't understand. After more investigation it turns out that we just need to pass null in "keyId" argument and this is it. I should have guessed that earlier based on your answers :)

Comment: Good job on that buddy. I guess I should've said 'pass key ID as null' instead of 'you shouldn’t specify the alias or key ID'. They should add a constructor that doesn't need the key ID - that's a design flaw. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was actually pretty simple. When `AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2` uploads the data it uses "Encrypt" (through GenerateDataKey which gives you an encrypted and an unencrypted version of the key. Encrypted key is then uploaded to S3 in the metadata. Part of the encrypted key has information which CMK was used to produce the key. It means that we no longer need to send KeyId when we Decrypt the data.
In `AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2` I was using the same encryption materials for `PutObjectAsync` and `GetObjectAsync` in the following way:

```
new EncryptionMaterialsV2(configuration.KeyId, KmsType.KmsContext, new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Unfortunately when we call `GetObjectAsync`, the library uses the provided KeyId to decrypt the data. For symmetric algorithms this is optional argument since KeyId is part of the metadata in the uploaded s3 object so there is no need to provide it again. The solution is pretty simple, we just need to recreate `AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2` without providing key id.

```
 var s3EncClient2 = new AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2(credentials, config, new EncryptionMaterialsV2(null, KmsType.KmsContext, new Dictionary<string, string>()));
```